# Azcopy fails while executing thorugh powershell

Tags: azure-powershell

Getting the below error while executing azcopy from powershell.

```
$args = "/Source:\\UNCservcer\env\older /Dest:https://1234env.blob.core.windows.net/folder1/folder2  /DestKey:hsyugf-*********== /S /XO /V:\\uncserver\SHARE\folderlog\log_123.log"
$exepath  = "F:\Prgrm flss\azcopy\AzCopy.exe"
Start-Process   $exepath $args-Wait
```

I used the above code and got this error.

```
Error parsing destination location "https://1234env.blob.core.windows.net/folder1/folder2": The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I removed the the log(/V) and tried. But no luck.
I could see some solutions like to disable the the firewall and run azcopy as an adminstrator. But I am restricted to do this stuffs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the [AzCopy v10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10), it's a more convenient and currently supported version. When you use it, the command is simple and like this:

```
azcopy copy /path/to/folder "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/data/sas_token" --recursive=true
```

**Update:**

Here is the screenshot that how to generate the SAS token:

[image]

Comment: Hi,
I tried with your above command but getting the below error.
    `failed to perform copy command due to error: no sas token or Oauth token is present and the resource is not public.`

I dont't have SAS token either. How do I execute without SAS token.  I have only the authentication key.

Comment: @DineshKumar If you do not want to use the SAS token, you can use the service principal with the role `Storage Blob Data Contributor` or `Storage Blob Data Owner`. Take a look at the steps [How to assign an RBAC role for access to blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#assign-rbac-roles-using-the-azure-portal). And then you can log in with the command `azcopy login --service-principal --application-id <application-id> --tenant-id=<tenant-id>`. I think the SAS token is more simple :-)

Comment: Hi Charles, I have the authentication key which is ending with == like this.
"hsyugf+vktfdDghhh/jyt*********==". I am not sure this the SAS token or not. Could you please confirm.

Comment: @DineshKumar I'm afraid not. You need to generate the SAS token in the portal.

Comment: Could you please help me on how to generate SAS token.

Comment: @DineshKumar Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.